# formatting timestamp from BigQuery to Google Spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-bigquery

I'm creating a spreadsheet that hits BigQuery with Apps Script.  Here's part of my query:

```
SELECT
  id,
  USEC_TO_TIMESTAMP(created) AS created,
  USEC_TO_TIMESTAMP(modified) AS modified,
  USEC_TO_TIMESTAMP(resolved) AS resolved,
  status_id,
FROM
  [mydata:mydataset.latest]
WHERE  blah blah blah...
```

When I run this from http://bigquery.cloud.google.com, I get timestamps that look like "2013-08-22 19:19:01 UTC" (this is great).  However, when I run the same query from a spreadsheet, I get dates that don't make sense.  If I remove the function USEC_TO_TIMESTAMP, the dates still don't make sense.  What I mean by "don't make sense", is that if I format the numbers as dates, I get garbage values.  What is the recommended way to query dates from a spreadsheet?

(from a mailing list)

Answer (score 3):

You should use FORMAT_UTC_USEC() instead of USEC_TO_TIMESTAMP().